# MATLAB: char(x) yields Conversion to char from logical is not possible

Tags: matlab, type-conversion

I have some code necessary for my research, and the developer does not have the time to troubleshoot this with me, so I am hoping I can get some help here:

I am thinking this is a MATLAB version issue (possibly) because it seems pretty straight forward.  Here's the code that causes the grief:

```
y = char(x);
```

The output is:

> Error using char
>
> Conversion to char from logical is not possible.

Yep.  If I do `disp(x)` I get:
`0`

Can anyone tell me if there is a version/syntax/whatever issue here?

Comment: As gnovice said, converting logical to double to char will give pretty strange ASCII control characters. If what you want is a _string representation_ of `x`,  use `mat2str`: `x = false; y = mat2str(x);` gives `y = 'false'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really trust the function [`disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html) in this case. It will show `0` or `1` for logical values. For example:

```
>> disp(false)
   0
```

You should instead test the data type of `x` using the [`class`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) function, and I'm sure you'll see it return `logical`:

```
>> x = false;
>> class(x)

ans =

logical
```

If you want to force it to do the conversion anyway, you can convert the `logical` to a `double` like so:

```
y = char(double(x));
```

However, you will only ever get a null or start of header character ([ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/) for `0` and `1`) as a result.